# form select responsiveness inside of a card body - bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my code
https://www.codeply.com/go/dsqKr2ncWB

This is basically what I was hoping it would look like, it works in the largest resolution.

[Large res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9bK9.png)

Shrinking it down to tablet size seems to not resize the select

[tablet res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWxdB.png)

Resizing the select does seem to work when it gets really small around phone size though

[phone res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJMcH.png)

I've tried everything I could think of, anyone know what I should change? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to your use of `form-group`.  If you switch to `input-group` you can ensure a more consistent responsive change as your device size shrinks.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center">
          <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nullam</h1>
          <h2 class="font-weight-bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sita</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">
          
          <div class="input-group mx-0 mx-md-3">
            <select name="p" size="1" title="Department List" class="custom-select">
            <option value="%">-All-</option>
            <option value="TEST">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</option>
            <option value="TEST2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur amet</option>
            </select>
            
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-red" type="submit">Go</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tied the button to the `input-group` as well... this just makes sure that regardless of the screen size your button isn't going to jump to a new line.  `custom-select` has also replaced `form-control` to provide more consistent styling.

Note that I've also specified `mx-0` to ensure that the X-axis margin is correctly removed on smaller devices.  That seems to be something that Bootstrap's media queries don't *always* do without it being spelled out.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the select, but it does appear that the button still goes to a new line. This isn't that much of an issue, but it would be nice if it stayed together.

Comment: I would recommend double-checking all your formatting, the `input-group` component shouldn't ever allow a button inside `input-group-append` to fall to a new line.